# RestSharp doesn't get data or content of response

Tags: c#, php, json, postman, restsharp

I have a route in my web service that receives **POST** request with Json body and returns simple array in Json format. I'm using PostMan for testing route and it works perfectly. but when I'm using RestSharp it doesn't get any content (or data in deserialization case).

Here is my C# code :

```
public static async Task<string> UpdateProfile(Profile user, string serviceUrl)
    {

        string bodyraw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user)

        var client = new RestClient(serviceUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.Parameters.Clear();
        request.AddParameter("application/json", bodyraw, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

        var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<Profile>(request);

        return response.Data.Address;            

    }
```

And here is the Profile Class:

```
 public class Profile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Postal_code { get; set; }
    public string Education { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Default_contact { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat(Name," " ,Family, " ", Address);
    }
}
```

And this is *PostMan* OutPut:

```
{
    "Name": "Holma",
    "Family": "Kool",
    "Email": "dr@gmail.com",
    "Mobile": "09063094744",
    "Address": "some city- basic av. sq 60",
    "Postal_code": "10246666",
    "Education": "1",
    "Gender": "male",
    "Age": "35"
}
```

And the PHP code that I used is:

function silverum_update_user_profile($request ){

```
$parameters = $request->get_json_params();// this is a WordPress method and works just fine

$name=sanitize_text_field($parameters['name']);
$family=sanitize_text_field($parameters['family']);
$email=sanitize_text_field($parameters['email']);
$mobile=sanitize_text_field($parameters['mobile']);
$address=sanitize_text_field($parameters['address']);
$postal_code=sanitize_text_field($parameters['postal_code']);
$education=sanitize_text_field($parameters['education']);
$gender=sanitize_text_field($parameters['gender']);
$age=sanitize_text_field($parameters['age']);

$extdp = [
    "Name"=>$name,
    "Family"=>$family,
    "Email"=>$email,
    "Mobile"=>$mobile,
    "Address"=>$address,
    "Postal_code"=>$postal_code,
    "Education"=>$education,
    "Gender"=>$gender,
    "Age"=>$age
];


return $extdp;
```

}

When PHP method returns "Parameter" its OK and both PostMan and RestSharp can see output content but when method Returns new Array only PostMan is able to recive returnd object. I spent a couple of hour on the issue but didn't get anywhere. help please.

Comment: The best way is use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler .  Compare the first request from good results with bad results.  Make the bad results first request look like the good request.

Comment: Instead of request.AddParameter - try using request.AddJsonBody(user) then you don't need to serialize it manually either.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the AddJsonBody() method within the RestRequest object as opposed to adding the parameter manually.

```
public static async Task<string> UpdateProfile(Profile user, string serviceUrl)
{
    var client = new RestClient(serviceUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.AddJsonBody(user);

    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<Profile>(request);

    return response.Data.Address;            
}
```

Comment: I have updated my anwser, I changed ExecuteTaskAsync to ExecuteAsync<Profile>(request) and in my dummy application this is working. Let me know if this change resolves your issue.

Comment: If the issue still persists, please share the serviceUrl if this is not private. If it is ensure it is the full path to the endpoint, if it is not and is just something like https://myurl.com/api then you will need to add request.Resource = "function1"

Comment: thanks Rayan. the problem was solved. it raised because of case sensitivity in both json deserializer and PHP.

Comment: Glad you sorted it. :)